# How do I edit a "block" on my site?

Tags: blocks

I want to edit the text within a block on my site. However, the only options seem to be configure block and configure layout - neither of which gives me the option to edit the text. Suggestions? Click the link below to see what I'm talking about. Any help greatly appreciated!
Example of what I'm talking about: [enter link description here](http://www2.dallasbar.org/_upload/uploads/Document1%20(1).jpg)

Comment: What kind of block is it? If it’s a menu block, the titles of each link is configured in the menu configuration, not the block configuration.

Comment: THANK YOU Kevin! That was the problem!! SOOOO appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I added it as an official “answer” for you to accept below then.

Comment: Hey JSmith, if you ever return to this site (since you posted your last comment), wwill you then please use the correct way to say "THANK YOU" ... which is not to post a comment (like you did), but instead mark the answer from @KevinNowaczyk as accepted. While waiting for you to ever do so, I already did a "+1" of that answer ...

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a menu block, the titles of each link is configured in the menu configuration, not the block configuration.